# I am getting mongoDB socket exception in executable jar file but not in my intellij local. while connecting mongoDB atlas

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jar, atlas

I have created a java springboot application with mongodb Atlas as backend. In my local intellij idea it was totally working fine but when I created the executable jar file then I am getting following errors. I have made white listing my IP address in Atlas with 0.0.0.0/0 still it is not connecting the mongoDb

My github repo : https://github.com/Hussain486/item.git

```
19:50:19.043 [cluster-ClusterId{value='640ddfa3dc2dcd03c9d99fa5', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:73)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:183)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:585)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:68)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
19:50:19.045 [cluster-ClusterId{value='640ddfa3dc2dcd03c9d99fa5', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
```

My application.properties file

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://hussain1010486:Husainmohd486@cluster0.qgbxl1t.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.database=a2z
```

Comment: I hope you didn't post your actual credentials.

Comment: _"... Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017"_  Your app is trying to connect to your `localhost`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Credentials are correct! Yeah I am unsure why it was connecting to localhost:27017

Comment: You could include in your question the code where the connection is attempted, and where the parameters for connection are set/derived.